# How to exclude folder from compilation

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compilation, web-config

I developing a website (with Umbraco CMS) that uses `Media` folder as repository for images, documents, every uploaded file with BackOffice interface.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with ReSharper 8. Web site is in local server. I'm developing web site through SMB protocol to shared folder in local server.
My project has `Media` folder with 5200 subfolders. Any subfolder contains at least 2 files.

My tedious issue is that when I do "save" a `App_Code` file, Visual Studio freeze for 15 seconds. I look that my PC do something a folder scan every time I do `save`.

Then I would try to exclude `Media` folder from compiling web site. So, maybe, I will gain some seconds.

Can I add a `web.config` file inside `Media` folder with settings to force the compiler to Exclude the folder from compilation?
Can you give me an example?

Comment: Does the media folder even need to be in the solution/project?

Comment: What makes you think this is what your PC is working on?

Comment: @bzlm: sounds like he's using a web site "project"

Comment: `Media` folder contains files that they will be reachable from URL.

Comment: @John, I think that Visual Studio recompile entire project to build a dictionary of objects and methods.

Comment: No, Visual Studio only recompiles files which have changed

Comment: @John, is it possibile that ReSharper ask to Visual Studio to rebuild all project, after the change of one file? I think that it is the behavior. Visual Studio is always super-fast with ReSharper disabled.

Comment: @riofly: ReSharper has no effect on the build system.

Comment: No, ok, but ReSharper invoce a compilation command to works: http://hmemcpy.com/2010/12/my-talk-at-the-alt-net-israel-tools-meetingresharpers-hidden-gems/